# Python 3.3 urllib memory leakage

Tags: memory, urllib, python-3.3

I'm using Mac mini with iOS 10.9.2 and Python 3.3.
I wrote a simple Python app, which fetches api data and shows some calculation.
Everything is working well, but I saw in Activity Monitor (os tool) that after a few connections the system memory usage increases, but in my opinion it shouldn't. I wouldn't publish application that can eat all memory so I need some help.

Here is a piece of my code which makes this problem:

```
import urllib.request
import time

class Main(object):
    def Get(self, url):
        urlData = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        for line in urlData:
            line = str(line,'utf-8')
            print( line.rstrip() )
        urlData.close()
        time.sleep(1)

M = Main()
url = "https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/trades"
b=1

while b>0:
    M.Get(url)
    b=b+1
```

I've tried to do it in another way but it increases the memory usage, too:

```
req = request.urlopen('https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/trades')
urlData = json.loads(req.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

This increases the memory usage, too:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
html = urlopen("https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/trades")
```

Thank you in advance!